# Laravel Relationship 1-2-1

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I've a tables what looks that:

Users:

> id | username | password | ...

Users_Services

> id | user_id | service_id | active | paidTo

And Services:

> id | title | description | type | price | active

I want get services of current user with all data about it from another table, so my relationship should looks:
[image: Relationship]

I don't know how can I do that on "User_Services" class, in Controller I've:

> $services = User::find( Auth::user()->id )->services;

User class:

```
public function services() {
        return $this->hasMany('User_Services');
}
```

And Services class:

```
public function user_services()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('User_Services', 'User', 'service_id');
}
```

Now how about User_Services class, how can I do that relationship?

Comment: are you looking for a query to do that for you ?

Comment: I Want to this without query. I know how do this in SQL but idk how in Eloquent ORM.

Comment: `Auth:user()` will get you an instance of the user.. no need to do `User::find`

Comment: @watcher Thanks, I'll remember this for the future :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From User class you can declare both relationships.
Edit: I got confused by the arrows: If the relation is 1-N_1-N

```
class User extends Eloquent {

    public function services()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('Services', 'Users_services');
    }
    public function usersServices()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Users_services');
    }
}
```

If it is many to many 1-N_N-1
    class User extends Eloquent {

```
    public function services()
    {
        return $this->belognsToMany('Services', 'Users_services');
    }
}
class Services extends Eloquent {

    public function services()
    {
        return $this->belognsToMany('Users', 'Users_services');
    }
}
```

Comment: What should I add to User_Services class?

Comment: For the relationship to work, nothing. If you have specific columns of the relation there, you can access them with: http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#working-with-pivot-tables

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are actually looking for a many-to-many relationship which in Laravel is going to be defined with the `belongsToMany()` function.  You can set those up like so...

```
class User extends Eloquent {

    public function services() 
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Service')->withPivot('active', 'paidTo');
    }
}

class Service extends Eloquent {

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('User');
    }
}
```

The `withPivot()` part is grabbing those additional columns you have on your `User_services` table.

Now getting a user's services should be very easy and can be done like so...

```
$services = Auth::user()->with('services');

foreach($services as $service) {
    echo $service->description;

    // If you need to display information from the pivot table, that can be done like so.
    echo $service->pivot->paidTo;
}
```